# How would I use a JSON name of "1" (or any other number) without it getting regonized as Int?

Tags: json, haxe

If for example I have `"all_stations_info": {"1": {"playing": "some song"}, "2": {"playing": "another song"}}` and I want to get the song playing on station "1", how'd I do it without the "1" getting recognized as Int or Float?
typedef doesn't work since it, too, doesn't want an Int, and I'm not sure DynamicAccess can be used with remote data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `haxe.DynamicAccess<Any>` as type then you can just use array access like this `all_stations_info["1"]`.

> [DynamicAccess](https://api.haxe.org/haxe/DynamicAccess.html) is an abstract type for working with anonymous structures that are intended to hold collections of objects by the string key. DynamicAccess uses Reflect internally.

```
   var json:{ all_stations_info:haxe.DynamicAccess<Any> } = haxe.Json.parse('{"all_stations_info": {"1": {"playing": "some song"}, "2": {"playing": "another song"}}}');
    trace(json.all_stations_info["1"]);
```

Check: https://try.haxe.org/#2419b

---

If the type definition is very large, then it is good practice to define it as a typedef:

```
typedef StationsInfo = { all_stations_info:haxe.DynamicAccess<Any> }
```

Then you can use `var json:StationsInfo  = haxe.Json.parse('.....`

---

So, looking at what you posted, if you want it completely typed, then you could define the types like this:

```
typedef StationsInfo = { all_stations_info:haxe.DynamicAccess<StationData> };
typedef StationData = { playing: String };
```

Check: https://try.haxe.org/#C6F6d

Comment: Quicker and more detailed, perfect :P

Comment: Nifty, had no idea you could do this.

Comment: Yep, Haxe is great :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [Reflect](https://api.haxe.org/Reflect.html)?

Can find an example here: https://try.haxe.org/#c621C

Comment: I tried but didn't understand by myself, thanks for example!

Comment: You should take a look at @mark-knol answer too, it's a generally better approach (even if this one works too).

Comment: weird why this example link doesn't seem to work anymore, returning [object Object] instead of text...

Comment: First trace is of the "1" node, second is of the node names. If you wanted the contents of node "1" then you would need to call Reflect on the result. That said you should really use Mark Knol's solution.